# how to put "google search" and "bit.ly" minimizer input fields to my html?

Tags: html, url, google-search, minimize

i want to add "google search" and "bit.ly" url minimizer input (i guess i am talking about API?), to my website. how should i approach it, what i must do, to get those inputs working as well?

i must say that my developing knowledge is limited to html/css and some understanding (with google help) in javascript.

i tried to search on this topic, but did not find anything to go on with. so sorry, if this is someway already covered in some previous q/a post.

thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure how to put the bit.ly minimizer input field, but the google search is fairly simple.
 Click [here](https://cse.google.com/cse/all) and create a new google custom search engine. When it asks for sites to search, put in https://www.google.co.uk/

Then, do what it says. Customise it if you want.

I think that is what you wanted. It is a google API. Hope it helps.

Comment: hi Sankarsh. though the link under "here" seems to be invalid, i understand Your main message. i should dig into Google API more. will do that.

Comment: Oh sorry. I'll change that if i can now.